# Mapbox SDK Dependency download fail

Tags: java, android-studio, mapbox

I have not been able to get past step 1 of downloading the mapbox sdk through my dependencies.
I have implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:10.3.0'

I have followed the mapbox instructions to an aboslute T and after a sync, I run .gradlew app:dependencies and get the following output:+--- com.mapbox.maps:android:10.3.0 FAILED

When I sync, I do not get any errors in the event log or reported problems. It just doesn't download the SDK?

Perhaps I need to change permissions in studio? I am at a loss

Comment: Could you share full error that you're getting, please?

Comment: For sure. I just opened a fresh project to try again and looks like I am getting the following 3 errors:
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.mapbox.maps:android:10.3.0.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.mapbox.maps:android:10.3.0.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.mapbox.maps:android:10.3.0.

Comment: Problem has been solved. I did not create my token correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation was:
'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.3.0'
I also had to put the maven repo in settings.gradle instead of build.gradle

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).